# How to handle multiple values of features in a particular record in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-science

I have an use case for which I'm trying to solve it using Machine Learning. Let's say I have an input data in the form of `(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6)` and output value `Y`. Consider the following scenario where you have multiple values of (`X5` and `X6` and each set of them are correlated) for same fixed set of `(X1,X2,X3,X4)` and you have `Y` value changing for each set of (`X5` and `X6`), how do you formulate the data in training for a machine learning model?

I could only think of following ways to address the problem:

i. Have each row for each set of (`X5` and `X6`) value and introduce a rank categorical column to say these input data are correlated i.e :

> **X1 X2 X3 X4  X5  X6  Rank Y**
>   
>     *1.5 2 3.4 5.4  6.7  7.8   1    2.3
>   
>
>      1.5 2 3.4 5.4  4.32 6.3  1    7.4
>   
>  
>      1.5 2 3.4 5.4  2.1   2.3  1    3.24
>   
>
>      2.1 1 12  34   2  3.23   2    1.24
>   
>
>      1.5 2 3.4 5.4 6.7   7.8   3    24.4*

so on......

ii. Explode `X5` and `X6` features into multiple columns for each value of them, but the problem here is we have to limit the number of columns and the correlation is missing b/w `X5` and `X6`.

Below links are the code file and the input file attached for the existing realtime usecase with actual feature names and output variable.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=178XEzd_5iPXGMBJUrqI5kvlwnDspwMhP
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18SA42kDlQto-PnR5fUpAcvXKlimGidOj/view

Comment: your question is not clear but approach2 will not work for sure if X5 and X6 are numerical columns and exploding them will introduce the curse of dimensionality.

Comment: @rajatkabra, I have real time usecase where (X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6) refers to variables(MaterialCapacity MC, LeadTime LT, InventoryLevel IL, ResourceLoad RL, Demand D, Priority P) in a supply chain usecase which I'm trying to solve for the output of PlanOrder(PO).Consider scenario 1 where the D and P can multiple values each for the same first four variables and for each (D,P) there will be single PO. Consider scenario 2 there may be a case of single (D,P) for the above same set of first four variable values and the output PO can entirely differ from the set of the outputs in scenario 1.

Comment: @SuthariSandeep   So, Do you want to predict Y by X5, X6?     And, X5 and X6 is derived by a set of (X1, X2, X3, X4)?

Comment: I am still not sure what you are asking but in your question you asked how to create the dataset for training, then the answer will be to take the features as an ndarray and feed it into a regression model. If you are using python or any of its library, it will be way easier to do this. Your features will be  X1 to X6  and the target will be PO. You will need a regression model for this problem.

Comment: @SuthariSandeep Anyway, You need a regression model.  Please share your env and code.

Comment: @yahocho I have used a neural network to solve this usecase.I have attached the code and input data files

Comment: @rajatkabra I have edited the question to include my code and input files.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your code. But, I got your data.

I think `PRIORITY` and `SCHEDQT` are `y` data.

And, I uses `LEADTIME`, `BOMINV`, `BOMINFSW`, `SKUINV`, `SKUINFSW` and `COQTY` as `x` data. You must know the data is normalized simply in between 0~1.

It's better than before.
But, It's not predicted well. Please refer the result as below:

```
[`LEADTIME`, `BOMINV`, `BOMINFSW`, `SKUINV`, `SKUINFSW`, `COQTY`] [Pre. PRIORITY] [Real PRIORITY]
[0.03333333 0.33333333 0.         0.         0.         0.05666667] [8.221004] [18.]
[0.03333333 0.33333333 0.         0.         0.         0.26666667] [8.221004] [19.]
[0.03333333 0.33333333 0.         0.         0.         0.16666667] [8.221004] [20.]
[1.         0.         1.         0.         0.         0.16666667] [8.221004] [1.]
[1.         0.         1.         0.         0.         0.26666667] [8.221004] [2.]
```

I think Each field values can not make enough difference of `PRIORITY` result.

From the example as above, `LEADTIME`, `BOMINV`, `BOMINFSW`, `SKUINV` and `SKUINFSW` are same.

Then, I tried to remove some records if `LEADTIME` or `BOMINV` or `SKUINV` is `0`.

```
[0.2        0.33333333 0.         0.66666667 0.         0.33333333] [20.035915] [36.]
[0.2        0.33333333 0.         0.66666667 0.         0.46666667] [20.035915] [38.]
[0.2        0.33333333 0.         0.66666667 0.         0.6       ] [20.0352] [40.]
[0.2        0.33333333 0.         0.33333333 0.         0.16666667] [11.69006] [1.]
[0.2        0.33333333 0.         0.33333333 0.         0.26666667] [11.5476885] [2.]
```

But, You can see The result also very par from real because `x` data does not show enough difference.

Now, I can just say that you need more features of data to get enough learning.

Comment: Can `CODATE` and `RUNNAME` be the `x` data?

Comment: Code is provided here https://drive.google.com/open?id=178XEzd_5iPXGMBJUrqI5kvlwnDspwMhP. I'm able to access it and the download the ipython notebook as well.

Comment: Here 'SCHEDQTY' is used as output Y.And if you see there's a feature 'RUNNAME' about which my actual question is about.Here with RUNNAME value 'MAP_DL_1.1'  there are 10 records,I want to say these all 10 records are correlated. So how do I input this correlation to the neural network saying that all the records with same RUNNAME are correlated?

Comment: @SuthariSandeep  I got it. I will add `RUNNAME` to features.  I think I can do it 8 hours later.  Anyway, You told it is 10 records. I will convert it as 0~9. And It will be 0~0.9 by Normalization.

Comment: its not about just for 'MAP_DL_1.1' value for RUNNAME, its just for example to let u explain.I wanted to say that all the records in the data which contains same RUNNAME are correlated.